# How to display message in multiple div and not overlap eachpther when the window size changes

Tags: css

I have a container and displaying message .when I am changing window size the text is overlapping each other.
Here is my code.

```
<div id="msgRowInfo">
    <div  style="hieight:100%;width:100%">
            <div id="msgInfo">
                <div  id="msgType" >{{msg.msgType}}</div>
                <div id="msgTime" >{{msg.time}}</div>
            </div>
            <div  id="msgContent" >{{msg.subject}}</div>
            <div id="msgDescription" >{{msg.description}}</div>
     </div>    
</div>
```

Here is my css.

```
 #msgRowInfo{
        padding-top: 5px;
          padding-left: 5px;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          border-bottom: lightgrey;
          border-bottom-style: solid;
          border-bottom-width: thin;
          display: -ms-inline-flexbox
            }
        #msgInfo{
       width:100%;
    padding-left:1%;
      }
        #msgType{
        display: inline-flex;
          font-size: 20px;
          width: 70%;
        }
        #msgTime{
        width:27%;
         display: inline-block;
          float: right;
          text-align: right;
          padding-right: 3%;
        }
        #msgContent{
        padding-left: 1%; 
        width:100%;
        font-size: 20px;
        }
```

when I was resizing msg.msgType and msg.time is overlapping. How to not overlap each other and window size reducing it should come to next line.could somebody help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#msgRowInfo {
   padding: 5px;
   border-bottom: lightgrey 1px solid;
   font-size: 20px;
 }
 #msgInfo {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   background-color: red;
   
 }
 #msgType {
   background-color: pink;
   /* flex basis sets a minium width of the message type so message time wraps */
   flex: 1 1 75%;
 }
 #msgTime {
   background-color: tan;
 }
```

```html
<div id="msgRowInfo">
  <div id="msgInfo">
    <div id="msgType">{{msg.msgType}}</div>
    <div id="msgTime">{{msg.time}}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="msgContent">{{msg.subject}}</div>
  <div id="msgDescription">{{msg.description}}</div>
</div>
```

I was not really sure here exactly what you are looking for so I made a best guess.  I have removed a lot of the css and some html.  Sometimes reducing the complexity will help you solve the issue.  I have also added some background color so you can see what is going on.  Please let me know if you have questions.  The application of display flex to the message info area will stop overlap of the Type and Time.  Hope this helps.

Of course this is just one way to solve the issue there are many others.